# How to update the data from the searchResultsController (UISearchController)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, uisearchcontroller

So I am using a `searchResultsController`, which takes an array of Strings, and shows them in a tableview (It's an autocomplete list). When the user presses the 'Search' button on the keyboard, and the entered String is not yet in my Tableview, I want to add it, and update the tableview accordingly.

The issue is that once I added a String to the array, and make a new search, the array isn't updated with the new value!

Here is my code:

In my ViewDidLoad() on the Overview.swift class

```
    class Overview: UIViewController,UISearchControllerDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

        var mySearchController : UISearchController! 
        var mySearchBar : UISearchBar!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        let src = SearchResultsController(data: convertObjectsToArray()) 
            // instantiate a search controller and keep it alive
            mySearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: src)
            mySearchController.searchResultsUpdater = src
            mySearchBar = mySearchController.searchBar
        //set delegates
            mySearchBar.delegate = self
            mySearchController.delegate = self
}
```

This is the data function, used for the `UISearchController`

```
   func convertObjectsToArray() -> [String] {

    //open realm and map al the objects
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let getAutoCompleteItems = realm.objects(AutoComplete).map({$0})

    ...
    return convertArrayStrings // returns [String] with all words
}
```

So when the user pressed the search button on the keyboard, I save that word to my database.

Now I need to put the updated version of `convertObjectsToArray()` in my `searchResultsController`, but I haven't found out how to do this. All help is welcome

And last, but not least, my `SearchResultsController` class, which is used in the viewDidLoad of my `Overview.swift` class.

```
    class SearchResultsController : UITableViewController {
    var originalData : [String]
    var filteredData = [String]()

    init(data:[String]) {
        self.originalData = data
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.filteredData.count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = self.filteredData[indexPath.row]          
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        clickedInfo = filteredData[indexPath.row]    
    }



    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

}
```

For the filtering of my words in the tableview (when user types something, only matching Strings are shown), I use the following extension.

```
extension SearchResultsController : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let sb = searchController.searchBar
        let target = sb.text!
        self.filteredData = self.originalData.filter {
            s in
            let options = NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch
            let found = s.rangeOfString(target, options: options)
            return (found != nil)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search controller's update function for that I think:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    convertObjectsToArray()
    self.tableView.reloadData()


}
```

Comment: I use the function already as an extension, and this doesn't give my data from one class to the other, right?